# Mocha/Chai async tests 'done()' fn not working

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm testing a bank model I have as follows:

```
describe('Bank Model - Ajax', function () {

    it('loads bank', function (done) {

        var bank = new Bank();

        bank.OnLoaded = _(function () {
            expect(this.id).to.eql(1171);
            expect(true).to.eql(false);
            done();
        }).bind(bank);

        bank.load(1171);


    });
});
```

The load call makes an ajax request to my server. My problem is that `expect(true).to.eql(false);` throws an `Uncaught Assertion Error` and I'm not sure why. I'm using the recommended Mocha strategy of ending my test case with a done. Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Um, you're expecting `true === false`?

Comment: @muistooshort the point is that the assertion should be caught by the test case; it shouldn't be an uncaught error.

Comment: But doesn't the `expect...` stuff raise exceptions when an assertion fails? I'm not an expert with Mocha or Chai so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Yes it does, but those exceptions should be caught by the test case and the results of the assertion errors printed nicely on my TestRunner page. That's not happening in this case.

Answer (score 9):

You're not doing anything wrong. Mocha isn't easily able to catch exceptions that are thrown within a callback since they execute after the test function has finished, so any failed assertions are uncaught fatal errors instead of nice diffs that you normally get with synchronous code.

People are working on workarounds such as [providing a custom method that assertion libraries can call instead of throwing](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/pull/985), or [using Node Domains when running in Node](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/513). But for now it seems that it is still not behaving ideally.

Since the `done` method accepts a single parameter containing an error, you can add code to your test to catch exceptions within the callback and pass them to `done(err)` inside the catch block. But it'd get pretty messy fast.

Could reduce repetition with some sort of helper function like the below:

```
function catching(done, fn) {
  try {
    fn();
    done();
  } catch(err) {
    done(err);
  }
}
```

And then:

```
bank.OnLoaded = catching(done, _(function () {
  expect(this.id).to.eql(1171);
  expect(true).to.eql(false);
}).bind(bank));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had assumed that because the callback is being referred to is inside the it() call, then the it() fn isn't expunged from memory because there's a reference to that callback somewhere. Is that inaccurate?

Comment: In terms of memory, yes the closure of the it() function is maintained since the callback's inside it. But the callback is _invoked_ outside of the it() function, so it can't catch any exceptions in the traditional way. By the time the exception happens, the it() function has already finished.